LVM + lvcreate has detected an XFS filesystem signature on the logical + how to force the creation or wipe automatically
The following warning we are encountering occurs because lvcreate has detected an XFS filesystem signature on the logical volume lv_rocket_lvm, which means it may already contain data formatted with XFS. The lvcreate command is asking if we want to wipe that signature to create the new logical volume.
one solution we can force the creation of the logical volume and wipe any existing data (including the filesystem signature), so we can proceed by answering y (for yes) when prompted. However, because we are running this command in a script we want to bypass the confirmation, so we use the --yes flag to force it. (still not tested this on my linux OS)
example from our rhel 7.x server
 lvcreate -n lv_rocket_lvm --size 100g VGlinux
 WARNING: xfs signature detected on /dev/VGlinux/lv_rocket at offset 0. Wipe it? [y/n]:

example of my suggestion
lvcreate -n lv_rocket_lvm--size 100G --yes /dev/VGlinux/lv_rocket 

other option is to erase separately the volume like
wipefs --all --force /dev/VGlinux/lv_rocket 

and then
 lvcreate -n lv_rocket_lvm --size 100g VGlinux

bedside my solution I want to know if there are other options?
Note - lv_rocket_lvm not appears from lvdisplay
lvdisplay  | grep "LV Path"
  LV Path                /dev/VGlinux/lvm_swap
  LV Path                /dev/VGlinux/lvm_var
  LV Path                /dev/VGlinux/lvm_root


You have enough reputation to understand how to examine the switches of lvcreate and to see what is available and to Google anything that isn't immediately evident. If this is a production system, then certainly you have a test or dev system where you create a logical volume to see what occurs with the various options.

what is interesting is lvdisplay not display the volume , so I am little confuse why lvcreate complain about this  ( lvdisplay  | grep -i lv_rocket )

You can disable signature wiping:
lvcreate --wipe-signatures n …

It's also possible to disable signature wiping in lvm.conf:
allocation {
    wipe_signatures_when_zeroing_new_lvs = 0
}

However, this only disables signature detection. lvcreate still wipes by zeroing the first 4K of the LV unconditionally. So if you want to disable wiping altogether, you also have to add --zero n (there does not seem to be a lvm.conf equivalent to that one). This will result in WARNING: Logical volume … not zeroed. but creates the LV regardless.
Alternatively, you can create it read-only and switch it back to read-write afterwards:
lvcreate --permission r …
lvchange --permission rw …

lvcreate skips wiping when creating read-only LV, and doesn't care anymore when changing it to read-write later.
If you create LV without wiping signatures, it's up to you to follow up with your own wiping method later (wipefs, blkdiscard, …) or leave it to mkfs.
If data recovery is your goal, disabling wiping is not enough. You have to make sure the LV uses the exact same extents as the LV you're trying to recover.
